# Power BI desktop - REST API refresh times out

Tags: rest, powerbi, refresh

I'm connecting to a REST API to bring several tables into a Power BI file. I can connect to the API and retrieve the data without any issues using 'Get Data > Other > Web' from the main toolbar, and then entering a URL in the format:

`https://api01.naturalhr.net/2.0/timeoff/key/(security key here)/format/xml`

The data usually comes back quite quickly - within about 10-20 seconds.

My issue is that when I try to refresh the same data it usually times out after 5-ish minutes. To refresh I go to 'Transform Data (I think this was 'Edit Queries' in earlier versions) > Select the query I'm interested in (in this case 'timeoff') > Select the 'Refresh Preview' button on the main menu.

The source in the formula bar in the Power Query editor is again just:

`= Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://api01.naturalhr.net/2.0/timeoff/key/(security key here)/format/xml"))`

So I'm just trying to refresh the same URL with which I'd retrieved the data without any issues, but for some reason it is at best taking much longer, and more commonly just timing out altogether.

Note that I do have some transformations to the original data, but even when I remove all of these I am still seeing the time-out.

Can anyone explain why I can get, but not refresh, the same data? Many thanks.

###EDIT:
To add some further information to this, I've used the new-ish Power BI diagnostic tools to try to troubleshoot this. What I've noticed is that while the **Resource** column displays the original URL, the **Data Source Query** column appends the text 'HTTP/1.1' to the original URL. Please see the screenshot below. If I try to establish a new connection with the added text, the query times out. Can anyone tell me why the extra text is added, why this prevents the data being returned, and how I can work around this? Thanks

[Power BI Diagnostics Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6et4.png)

Comment: Have you already tried fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) and took a look at the log? If not, download it, close all other windows beside power bi and run fiddler.

Comment: I would say that it was the transformations you do on the data, but you said you removed them and it still timed out... so I'm not sure anymore. I'm posting a different way for you to try connect to the API and you tell me if it remains the same.

Comment: Thanks both - currently waiting for tech support to install Fiddler.

Comment: Ok I see the edit, you found your culprit (I think). I have no clue how to get around that though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in a blank query:

```
let

    GetData = 
        let 
            source = Web.Contents("https://api01.naturalhr.net/2.0/timeoff/key/(security key here)/format/xml"),
            xml = Xml.Document(source)
        in
            xml
in
    GetData
```

Use Fiddler like @Rick Grimes said to see if your request is being sent normally.

Comment: (Same issue with the above query - initial query runs fine but refresh does not...still awaiting Fiddler install)

Comment: Okay. Fiddler will give you more insight as why are your requests taking more time than the first (I hope)

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll be notified that I've edited the post to add more info, so will also comment here. Any suggestions much appreciated.